# Dulwich cheat sheet: how to reproduce “git log”?

Tags: git-log, dulwich, git-rev-list

Dear community members,

I'm working on a code analysis system and would like to replace calls to CLI Git application with Dulwich module. As a second step I need to replace "git log" command with Dulwich equivalent.

Specifically, I'm trying to reproduce the following command:

```
git log --format=%H -- <path_to_a_file>
```

which must be similar to:

```
git rev-list HEAD -- <path_to_a_file>
```

My ultimate goal is to get a list of blobs (e.g. represented with SHAs) related to a given file.

What would be the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The function `dulwich.porcelain.log` provides an implementation roughly equivalent to the ''git log'' command.

See https://www.dulwich.io/code/dulwich/blob/master/dulwich/porcelain.py#L-570

Comment: Thanks @jelmer, it's exactly what I need!